# Multi-table count() in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, group-by

I have a table `events` which has `id` and `venue` columns.

The `events.venue` column matches the `venues.id` column, a fairly typical and simple setup.

Some of the venues are 'broken' in that they are missing critical pieces of information, such as `geo_lat`. I am trying to create a priority list of broken venues, with the `venue` that is hosting the most `events` at the top, so that we know which `venues` are most important to fix.

Myquery so far looks like;

```
select x.venue_id as id, count(x.venue_id) as events 
from (
    select * 
    from events e, venues v 
    where e.venue=v.id and v.geo_lat is null 
    group by e.venue
) as x order by events desc
```

Which is giving the error:
**ERROR:  column "e.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function**

The output I am trying to achieve would look something like;

```
venue.id | events
---------|-------
      12 |    219
     214 |    141
      36 |     41
    1834 |     22
     931 |      4
```

Containing just the *broken* venues. That way, I know that fixing venue `12` is top priority and so on.

Comment: With questions like this where you're showing your original queries, it can be really helpful to show `CREATE TABLE` statements and sample data `INSERT`s, along with the expected output you helpfully showed. It makes it much easier to test queries and means folks writing answers don't have to make their own dummy tables and data.

Comment: @CraigRinger thanks, i'll keep that in mind for next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
  venue.id,
  COUNT(events.venue)    AS event_count
FROM
  venues
LEFT JOIN
  events
    ON events.venue = venue.id
WHERE
  venue.geo_lat IS NULL
GROUP BY
  venue.id
ORDER BY
  COUNT(events.venue) DESC
```

The `LEFT JOIN` allows for venues with no events.  *(`INNER JOIN` would filter them out.)*